# How to add order form in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, paypal

I am new to Drupal :(

I need to add form in Drupal. In that i have to set package from dropdown and according to that payment  has to be done,

so click on submit button i should be redirect to paypal.

So for that which module needs to install?

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pretty much all your Drupal form needs check out the Webforms module - http://drupal.org/project/webform

**EDIT:**

To integrate this with PayPal you can use another module - http://drupal.org/project/webform_paypal

Install both and you will be able to do what you need.

Comment: yes, thanks for answer, but click on submit whole form data send to paypal and redirect to paypal how?

Comment: i have added those modules, next how can I proceed further?

Comment: Add a new webform and follow the set up process. Should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: I get how to create web form but still have problem how to integrate my whole html integrated form in that? and set form components in form design?